# How to lock specific range in worksheet but don't lock sheet

Tags: excel, vba, locking

I want to protect only range D1:D9 in my worksheet to prevent users from editing. However, I do not want to protect the whole sheet. Is there a way to go about this? I've been reading through posts and trying to implement their codes etc, but none of them seem to work for me. Your help is greatly appreciated!!

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Set Sheet1 = Sheets("Screening Request")
Sheet1.Cells.Locked = False

Sheet1.Range("D1:D9").Locked = True

' set the value
Sheet1.Protect

End Sub
```

Comment: "Locked" doesn't mean "Protected". You need the "locked" cells `Locked`, and the other cells unloked - then you `Protect` the sheet and decide how interactive the locked cells are for the users (i.e. whether or not they can select them)

Comment: sorry, I meant protected cells omy...I will edit my question. Maybe I have been searching the wrong stuff....Thank you for informing me! @MathieuGuindon

Comment: No, what I mean is that you *lock* cells and *protect* a sheet. When the sheet isn't *protected*, locked cells have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: oh....hm...I think I get confused with the lock and protected part...but the main idea is i only want range D1:D9 to be uneditable for users @MathieuGuindon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works as expected and can be run multiple times if you ever want to change the locked range:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim MySh As Worksheet
Set MySh = Sheets("Screening Request")
MySh.Unprotect
MySh.Cells.Locked = False
MySh.Range("D1:D9").Locked = True
MySh.Protect
End Sub
```

It unprotects the sheet so it wont throw an error from the last time you protected it. Then unlocks all cells, so only the specified range is locked and nothing else. Then it locks the specified range. Then it re-protects the sheet.

**Edit** As per psyduck's comment merged cells are an issue when working with ranges. In this case two columns are fully merged so the range can be altered to `D1:F9` in cases that it's not the entire range which is merged do separate instances like so:

```
MySh.Range("D1:D8").Locked = True
MySh.Range("D9:F9").Locked = True
```

Thanks to Mathieu Guindon for the suggestion.

Comment: hello! I tried the code but it says  "Run-time error 1004" Unable to set the locked property of the range class. Could it be because my cells D:F are merged?

Comment: @psyduck yes, merged cells are relevant and problematic.

Comment: ohnoooo.....then how can i still lock/protect(?) the range? @MathieuGuindon

Comment: @psyduck include all the merged cells in the range you lock, and it should work fine.

Comment: its ok Plutian:) I'm more rookie here haha ..hm..it still says "Run-time error 1004" Unable to set the locked property of the range class.I think because my cells D:F are merged..

Comment: @Psyduck if you have the entire range of D1:D9 merged with the entirety of F1:F9 it's easy, just change your range to D1:F9.

Comment: OMG Plutian and @MathieuGuindon thank you so much!! No more errors now when I open my workbook and the lock works, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

1. [Unlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.locked) all cells:

   ```
   ws.Cells.Locked = False
   ```
2. Lock yours

   ```
   ws.Range("D1:D9").Locked = True
   ```
3. [Protect](https://www.google.rs/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiA3d3J0ZHkAhWLwqYKHRPwAJYQFjABegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Foffice%2Fvba%2Fapi%2Fexcel.worksheet.protect&usg=AOvVaw2TxAIL6-jxeZnQ9Uoj3XVf) the specific sheet.

   ```
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   ' set the value
   ws.Protect
   ```

Comment: Don't you have the order mixed up? Lock, then protect?

Comment: this is throwing up an error for me...it says "Object variable or with variable not set". I put it in `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

Comment: @BigBen You are correct. I see someone updated the answer.

Comment: @psyduck don't put it in the `Change` handler... it's code that only needs to run once

Comment: @MathieuGuindon sorry... where should I place this in? could i place this in workbook_open?

Comment: @psyduck that would be one valid spot. Another could be any `Public Sub` procedure that you can invoke whenever you want, be it from another procedure or from the *immediate* pane (Ctrl+G)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon yikes...when I place it in thisworkbook, `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`, when i re-open the workbook, it throws up the error **"Compile error in hidden module: ThisWorkbook. This error commonly occurs when code is incompatible with the version, platform, or architecture of this application".** Just like my previous trial and errors.....I'm not too sure why tho

Comment: @psyduck replace `ws` with `Sheet1` or whatever code name you have for the sheet you want to work with - you only need to declare (`Dim`) a worksheet if you're working with a sheet that doesn't exist in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time. You can modify any sheet's code name from the *properties* toolwindow (F4) by changing the `(Name)` property to any valid VBA identifier.

Comment: Wait how the heck is `ThisWorkbook` a "hidden module"?

Comment: I changed my code but it the error that shows up now is  "Object variable or with variable not set". See my updated post! Hmm... could it be because I set a VBA password in my VBA settings?..

Comment: You are not setting the Sheet1 variable. add Set Sheet1 = Sheets("Sheet1").

Comment: ah.....oops...ok I updated the code in my post ..but it throws another error.. "Run-time error 1004" Unable to set the locked property of the range class. Could it be because my cells D:F are merged?

Comment: oh i forgot to @MathieuGuindon !! above^

Comment: hi EyIM, it works now and the errors could have been caused by the merged cells...(see answer below) but thank you so much!!